# Appearing a Notification for each specific Time android Application

Tags: java, android, time, triggers, notifications

How can program a variable in my android application that causes appearance of a notification for each 8 minutes, and after 2 hour it should  stop !
thanks in advance ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a service for this

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html